# C Pointers, Linked Lists and Nodes

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, nodes

I have been working on this code for a couple of days now and this is where i have come up to(i have asked before here). Point of code is to print number of occurences of each letter ona given string changing only `letters()` and `report()`.

I have added the `printf` in the `letters()` so to see whats going on.  I am not quite sure if in functions `letters()` the first loop is needed  but it is printing the whole inputed string. Also,if I dont put the first loop in `letters()` then in `report()` current is `NULL`(why???) . The second loop in `letters()` prints only the last letter of the inputed string(again why?). And `report()` again only prints the last letter of the string and the `current->occurences` prints a random 6-digit number(probably mem adress?),also reports goes on for ever, which means current never becomes `NULL`??? . I have been working on this for days and I cannot understand why the second loop on `letters()` and `report()` wouldnt work, they seem  correct to me. Any help appreciated...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct charact {
    char ch;
    int occurs;
    struct charact *next;
};

typedef struct charact Char;
typedef Char * ListofChar;
typedef Char * CharNode_ptr;
void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * chars_ptr);
void report(ListofChar chars);
Char * createnode(char ch);


int main() {
    char name[50];
    ListofChar chars = NULL;
    scanf("%s", name);
    letters(name,&chars);
    report(chars);
    return 0;
}


Char * createnode(char ch) {
    CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr ;
    newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Char));
    newnode_ptr -> ch = ch;
    newnode_ptr -> occurs = 0;
    newnode_ptr -> next = NULL;
    return newnode_ptr;
}


void letters(char name[50],ListofChar* lst_ptr){
    ListofChar newnode ;
    newnode =(Char*)malloc(sizeof(Char));
    if(!newnode){printf("adinamia mnimis");}
    int i,j;

    for( i = 0 ; i < strlen(name)  ; i++){
        newnode->ch  = name[i] ;
        printf("Look: %c\n",newnode->ch);
        newnode->next = *lst_ptr ;
        *lst_ptr = newnode ;
        }

    for( i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++){
        for( j = 0 ; j < strlen(name) ; j++){
            if  (newnode->ch == name[i]){
                newnode->occurs++;
                printf("uhm : %c\n",newnode->ch) ;
                newnode = newnode->next;
                break;
                }
            printf("hey : %c\n",newnode->ch);
        }
    }

}




void report(ListofChar chars) {
    ListofChar current  ;
    current = chars ;
    printf("the occurences of each letter are:\n");
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%c :  %d\n", current->ch,current->occurs );
        current = current->next ;
    }
    if(current==NULL)printf("fail");
    return;
}
```

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger! The most important skill you will ever learn when coding is how to debug your own code. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ If you want help you need to tidy up your explanation, as this block of text is nearly unreadable. Tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: Quick note - avoid typedef on pointers, only will make your life miserable

Comment: Your teacher needs to learn how to write clear, maintainable C code.  Please suggest to your teacher to submit the problem code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: You need to call `createnode()` when (and only when) you encounter a letter that you haven't encountered before.  It needs to be inside the loop over each character in `name`,  not before it.

Answer (score 0):

> Also,if i dont put the first loop in letters() then in report() current is NULL(why???).

- it is NULL, because you don't do anything with it. You initialized it to NULL, then passed it to a function, didn't do anything with it and when it got to `report()` it was still NULL.

> The second loop in letters() prints only the last letter of the inputed string(again why?).

- it prints only the last letter, because in the first loop in `letters()` the only thing you do is to assign `newnode->ch` to the current letter and when the loop exits it will have the value of the last letter.

> And report() again only prints the last letter of the string and the current->occurences prints a random 6-digit number(probably mem adress?

- `report()` prints a random number, because you don't know what was 
  `newnode->occurs` value before you increment it in `letters()`.

> also reports goes on for ever, which means current never becomes NULL???

- it goes forever, because current always points to itself(your logic in the first loop in `letters()` is broken.

There are too many errors in this code. I suggest you sit and read more on the fundamentals of C - pointers.